# media queries not having desired effect

Tags: html, css

After using Chrome developer tools to try to identify the element to manipulate in media queries, I have not had any luck in making the banner responsive to tablet and iphone size. This is the url:

http://thursdaypools.mediafuel.net/innovations/fiberglass-pool-anchoring-system/​

If you resize it, you will see that the banner image does not change size at all and I have tried the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {         #video-header {           height: 240px;         } }

/*@media (max-width: 980px) {   .banner {     height: 30vh; } }*/
```

The code thats commented out was written by someone before me and it didn't work when I got it and what you see at the top is my effort after trying to work with what I had. Neither the #video-header nor .banner seem to be making any difference.

The code for that banner is this one:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="post-page" class="single-innovations-page content-area">   <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page-intro' ); ?>
<!--dancortes added this code below here-->
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/content','page-banner'); ?>         
  <?php if( get_field( 'product_video' ) ): ?>
    <div id="video-header" class="full-video">
    <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="<?php the_field( 'product_video' ); ?>?enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div onClick="closeVideo()" class="close-video">                                 
 <p>Close</p>
 </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?><!--product_video-->
  <main class="subpage-content">
   <div class="medium-wrapper">
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <div class="innovation-information">
         <?php the_field( 'innovation_information' ); ?>
       </div>
       <?php endwhile; else : ?>
         <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
       <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
</div><!--page-top-->
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background-size` to `.banner`

```
.banner {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Reduce the banner height to get rid of the empty space above and below the banner in media query for smaller screens.

Comment: Happy to help !